# Bootstrap animations not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm quite new to Angular/Bootstrap and I downloaded a template that I'm trying to modify and add features to go about learning.

I'm trying to have a collapsible sub-menu as such

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('overview')}"><a ui-sref="overview">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products">Products</a></li> <!-- a click on this should expand the div below... --> 
    <div class="collapse" id="products">
        <ul>
             <div ng-repeat="itemType in itemTypes">
                <li><a href="" class="list-group-item">{{itemType.Description}}</a></li>
             </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

My attempt is from [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp).

Instead of a button, I want the animation to be triggered by a click on an anchor.

I read a version of Bootstrap had problems with animation so I upgraded to `bootstrap#3.3.6`

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

EDIT: By not working I mean, nothing is happening. I can use an `ng-show` directive, but there's no smooth animation.

Comment: Are you bringing in `collapse.js` like the example you linked to?  The built-in animations in Angular are defined in CSS, not JS.

Comment: I don't think I am. Should I edit the `bower.json` file manually or there is a command to install it ? I tried `bower install bootstrap-collapse` and that said no such package.

Answer (score 3):

As the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) says,

> You can use **a link** with the `href` attribute, or a **button** with the `data-target` attribute. In both cases, the `data-toggle="collapse"` is required.

Change the anchor tag to use the `href` attribute instead of `data-target`.

```
<a href="#products" data-toggle="collapse">Products</a>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('overview')}"><a ui-sref="overview">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#products" data-toggle="collapse">Products</a></li> <!-- a click on this should expand the div below... --> 
    <div class="collapse" id="products">
        <ul>
             <div ng-repeat="itemType in itemTypes">
                <li><a href="" class="list-group-item">{{itemType.Description}}</a></li>
             </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding jQuery and bootstrap to my 'serve' gulp task and this works, without changing the view's code at all.